# wp7 access SIM programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, storage, sim-card

I am attempting to download a contact from a webservice and want to save it to the SIM card as a .vcf file in order to use the 'import from sim card' functionality on wp7.  I am not seeing any access to the sim card in the msdn refeference. Does anyone have an idea of if this is possible?
Thanks!
mark

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to access the underlying hardware of a wp7, this includes the sim card.

You could save each contact at a time using a `SavePhoneNumberTask`, but you would need to ask the user permission before it imports or your app will fail certification.

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph mentions, you cannot write directly to the SIM card. Given the extent of information available in VCF, I'd recommend using [`SaveContactTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394013%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to allow the user to save the details.

Doing so will navigate away from your application while the user saves the contact, but it will notify you after come back (even if they cancelled)