# Get user’s country from SIM card

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can I retrieve user’s country from SIM card?

I found this thread [wp7 access SIM programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850343/wp7-access-sim-programmatically), but it’s very old, maybe something changed since that time?

If I cannot do this, will be GPS the best way?
`RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` don’t work.

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? Are you looking for the country where the user currently is? Or the country/languages/... as found in the phone's setting?

Comment: @HDWProduction: It shows "United States" even if I set other country in Settings.

Comment: CultureInfo.Current(UI)Culture reflects some (not all) phone settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issuer identification number (IIN) on the SIM card includes country identification which can be 2 digits (say, 44 for the UK) or 3 digits (say, 352 for Luxembourg).

So theoretically it would be possible, but Windows Phone (and that includes version 8) does not allow reading the SIM card's data.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way: **IP Address Geolocating**.
It doesn't need an access to a SIM card. But it needs the Internet connection.

Retrieve the xml from here http://freegeoip.net/xml/ and get country from it.