# How to get device carrier and country within Windows Phone 8 SL

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to find the device brand to get device country and carrier, for example 000-HK to get Hong Kong or TIM for Italy (the same values that I can see within Extras and Infos app)

How I can do it? I've tried a library that reads registry files but I can't submit the app because I can't use that APIs

My project is a Windows Phone Silverlight with c#

Note: I don't need the SIM operator or the actual phone language

EDIT: I don't need the actual position of the user or the SIM operator, but the phone brand and carrier that sell the phone, for example the Lumia Icon should return that's an american phone with Verizon as brand

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get user’s country from SIM card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763196/get-user-s-country-from-sim-card)

Comment: As I writed within the note, I don't need the infos from the SIM, but from the phone, even without the SIM or a different SIM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string val = Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("OriginalMobileOperatorName") as string;

//I wanted this value...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no access to such information with the current API. The only thing about the phone you can get is the make and model.